# SQL Server 2012 Installation account gets locked

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, installation

I am trying to install SQL Server 2012 with a service account. Installation is successful but the service account gets locked.  How it can be removed?

I tried using another account and tried with my my own account but same happened

Comment: Is the service running? usually, lock-out happens with policy which triggers upon number of failed login attempts this can be removed simply from user properties (Local/AD)

Comment: which service ? if it is SQl service - yes once the account gets unlocked it 's running.

Comment: Hello @Ajay, Since the service running, have a look at SQL Error Log and see if any unexpected activity related to service account.

Answer (score 0):

Start the instance of SQL Server in single-user mode by using either the -m or -f options.

More information here: https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/118087-how-to-gain-access-to-sql-server-when-nobody-has-access

Comment: Thank you for your answer Fredrik. My question is account gets locked. SQl Server is perfectly installed without any issue , it's just the account which gets locked which is creating issues. I would like to give an example : : If I am using my account "MyAccountName" to install Sql Server. After installation my account will get locked,  now I can not log anywhere, so this is the problem. Once the account gets unlocked everything works well ( whatever is running with my account as an identity)

Comment: Computer Management > Local Users and Groups > Users. Right click on the user and select properties. Uncheck 'Account is locked out'.